# How do I find when a commit was merged to branch

Tags: git

Git blame shows a change made to a file. I want to know when that change was merged to our live branch.

I could probably track it down with a graphical client, but there's a lot of other commits going on. The commit was not in the first couple of merges to the live branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>`git show <commit_hash>` will give you details about the commit.</s>

Do this

`git rev-list <commit_hash>..<branch> --first-parent`

`git rev-list <commit_hash>..<branch> --ancestry-path`

The last row in common will be the commit hash you're looking for.

You can store them both in a separate file and then do `sdiff` to quickly identify it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want should be this:

```
git log --merges <interesting_hash>..<live_branch>
```

That at least seems to work in a one-time merge situation. Not sure how it will act in a continuous integration scenario, where multiple merges from between the two branches might have occurred (although in that case, at least it narrows down the set of places you need to look)...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your git flow is like this: you push tested code into `master` (or `production`) branch, and once you are ready, you simply pull the `master` branch on the production environment. In this case, if you want to know "when" you did the `pull` or `merge` (was it yesterday? last week?), you can use `reflog` as follows:

Command:
`git reflog show --date=default`

Output:

`5c4f140 HEAD@{Mon Aug 10 05:36:24 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
1ba6e4e HEAD@{Wed Aug 5 14:40:50 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
05382e4 HEAD@{Wed Jul 22 12:27:20 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
bad194c HEAD@{Wed Jul 22 09:54:01 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
016f6cb HEAD@{Sat Jul 18 04:53:56 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
b4839d3 HEAD@{Mon Jul 6 07:35:23 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward`